# Connecting a Firestore database to a Chrome Extension manifest v3

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, google-chrome-extension, firebase-security, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to build a chrome extension with a firestore database but with the new manifest.json v3 it seems rather complicated. I have used firebase before and done it successfully but not in the chrome extension. For some context, what I want is to have the extension to take a search input from the user in the popup, run it through the database, send it back and display it in the popup.

I have all the basics done for a extension, popup.html, manifest.json, background.js etc.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "extension try 5000",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My first Chrome extension",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["scripting", "tabs", "activeTab"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  }
}
```

So I have tried importing the standard config for firebase/firestore into the background.js file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

I believe that I can't do any useful coding inside the background script, such as taking input from the user and send to the database etc. If I have the firebase connection inside a seperate javascript file I get security errors so I need it in the background.js file. I have tried using the same connections to the same firebase project in a "normal" web application and it works just fine, so it's something with the chrome extension process that is the problem.

Also good to mention is that I have tried to import using NPM, Links provided from firebase and downloaded the files manually. None of those have worked for me yet, must be something im missing.

Thankful for some answers, been bugging me for days now..

Answer (score 0):

Your popup page communicates with the background service worker via [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage) and [`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessage). See [example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#example-content-msg)

my background script

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-app.js'
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signInAnonymously } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-auth.js'
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, getDoc } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-firestore.js'


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xyz",
  authDomain: "your-project-name.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "your-project-name",
  storageBucket: "your-project-name.appspot.com",
  appId: "1:1234567890:web:xyz"
};


// Initialize Firebase with a "default" Firebase project
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
if (firebaseApp) console.log(' Firebase App initiated');

const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
if (auth) console.log(' Auth initiated');

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  console.log('user', user)
})

signInAnonymously(auth)
  .then((signIn) => console.log(' signed in', signIn))
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log('error', error)
  });


export const getResponseInfo = async (formId) => {
  const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
  if (firestore) console.log(' Firestore App initiated');

  const docRef = doc(firestore, "form-responses", formId);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
    return docSnap.data();
  } else {
    // docSnap.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
    return null;
  }
}
```